# jquery post values to login .php

Tags: php, jquery

i am using the id of modal box button for submitting values to login.php. My jquery code is:

```
$('#login1').on('click', function () {
  $.post('login.php', {
      'u': $('#email').val(),
      'p': $('#password').val(),
      'r': $('#role').val()
  }, function (data) {
      if (data == 'success') {
          $('#myModal1').modal('show');
      }
      else {
          $('#myModal2').modal('show');
      }
  });
  return false;
});
```

login.php

```
   <?php
   $u=$_POST['u'];
   $p=$_POST['p'];
   $r=$_POST['r'];
   $p=md5($p);
   $mysqli=new mysqli('localhost','root','password','user_details');
   if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
     printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
     exit();
   }
   $q=$mysqli->query("select * from register_info where Email='{$u}' ,     Password='{$p}' and Role='{$r}'");
   $e=$q->num_rows;
   if($e>0)
   {
     $loggedIn=true;
     $result='success';
     $_SESSION['logged_in']=true;
     header('location: profile.php?email='.$u);
   }
   else
   {
     $loggedIn=false;
     $result='fail';
   }
   ?>
```

modal form code:

```
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="form-horizontal" action='login.php' method="POST">
            <br>
            <fieldset>
                <div id="legend">
                    <legend class="">Login Details</legend>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <!-- Username -->
                    <label class="control-label"  for="email">Email</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email" class="input-xlarge">
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="control-group">
                    <!-- Password-->
                    <label class="control-label" for="password">Password</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password" class="input-xlarge">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <!-- Password-->
                    <label class="control-label" for="role">Role</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <select name="role"  class="form-control input-sm" id="role"   placeholder="Enter role">
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <br>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" id="login1" data-dismiss="modal">Login</button>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">


    </div>
</div>
```

I want that when I click on the button of login modal box on successfully checking the email and password it should redirect me to the profile.php page. Please help me correct the code

Comment: instead of using comma(,) before password in `sql query` use `and`

Comment: try the query : `select * from register_info where Email='{$u}' AND Password='{$p}' AND Role='{$r}`

Comment: The problem is still not solved

Comment: you forget to start session at the top of your page

Comment: Also remove the return false and change to `$('#login1').on('click', function (e) { e.preventDefault();`

Comment: its still not redirecting the url

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your trying to send data from a form to a database. There is no returning values from your php code. its redirect to another page while user logged . hence i modified the php code that may help you...

```
<?php
       $u=$_POST['u'];
       $p=$_POST['p'];
       $r=$_POST['r'];
       $p=md5($p);
       $mysqli=new mysqli('localhost','root','password','user_details');
       if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
         printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
         exit();
       }
       $q=$mysqli->query("select * from register_info where Email='{$u}' ,     Password='{$p}' and Role='{$r}'");
       $e=$q->num_rows;
       if($e>0)
       {
         $loggedIn=true;
         $result='success';
         $_SESSION['logged_in']=true;

       }
       else
       {
         $loggedIn=false;
         $result='fail';
       }
    echo $result; // based on this open your modal window 
       ?>
```

Comment: I tried this but it is still not redirecting to the profile page

Comment: Based on response redirect it from HTML (using jquery)... for example if ur responses is $result='success' means redirect it otherwise show error in html

Comment: I used function (data) {
                  if(data=='success') {
                      var url='http://www.google.com';
                      $(location).attr('href', url);
                  }
              });      
 But this is still not redirecting it to the google page

Comment: Its still not redirecting

Comment: Whether its getting into if condition are not   f(data=='success') {  alert("in loop"); }

Comment: No it is not going in the if condition

Comment: Did you alert the data or responses get from php page

Comment: try this $('#login1').on('click', function () {
  $.post('login.php', {
      'u': $('#email').val(),
      'p': $('#password').val(),
      'r': $('#role').val()
  }, function (data) {
      alert(data) ;
  });
  return false;
});

Comment: Sorry Thanks for your help actually my login file was having a different extension

Answer (score 1):

You encountered one issue in the SQL query.

The other issue is that your jQuery needs to follow the redirection from the ajax post response, the following is untested code:

```
$('#login1').on('click', function () {
  $.post('login.php', {
      'u': $('#email').val(),
      'p': $('#password').val(),
      'r': $('#role').val()
  }, function (e, xhr) {
     location.href = '/profile.php';
  });
  return false;
});
```

Comment: I updated the line `location.href = '/profile.php';` - but that will always redirect to profile page